# Reference regex string In JSON response

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

How to reference regex string In the JSON response

```
url value(consumer(regex('/connectors/(.*?)/status')))
```

So that if I request `'/connectors/foo/status'` I get `{ "name": "foo" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/docs/current/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-referencing-request-from-response

You'd need to do

```
response {
  body(name: fromRequest().path(1))
}
```